# Grails UrlMappings to external remote files

Tags: grails, url-rewriting, url-mapping

In Grails, I'm trying to make it so that any requests to /images/* actually goes to another website on another host.

I know how to do it in Apache with Mod Rewrite, but how can I achieve this with UrlMappings?

I want

/images/*  to go to http://somedomain/images/*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly. You'll have to map it to a controller which will in turn `redirect` to the desired location. Something like:

```
"/images/$urlTail**"  (controller: "image", action: "external")
```

And then in the `external` method of the `ImageController`:

```
def actualUri = request.forwardURI.replace("/images/", "")
redirect "http://example.com/" + actualUri;
```

Comment: no easier way? If not, could you show how to pass the tail as a parameter?

Comment: @nute - see updated. I didn't find a way to pass the tail as parameter. It might be possible, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround I've found:

```
String url = <your-url>
java.net.URI uri = new java.net.URI(url)
return Response.seeOther(uri).build()
```